# CSS3's attr() doesn't work in major browsers

Tags: css

I have this in my HTML document:

```
<a class="wbutton tint" data-tint="rgba(255,0,0,.5)" href="#">This should be red, with an opacity of 0.5</a>
```

and this in the CSS file:

```css
.window > .content .wbutton.tint {
    border: solid thin attr(data-tint, color);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px attr(data-tint, color);
}
```

Firefox returns a CSS error in Firebug. Am I doing something wrong?

According to the [W3C specs for the `attr()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#attr-notation), it should work.

(Also, there's [a page about `attr()` in the MDN Wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/attr), so I assume it should at least work in Firefox)

Comment: I'm pretty sure "attr()" is not part of CSS3, or any other CSS, even if it, CSS3 is still a draft, and even the very latest browsers don't have full support yet.

Comment: @Hosh Sadiq: It is. See my answer.

Comment: `attr()` is currently only supported at the `content` property, which can be used for pseudo-elements (such as `:before`, `:after`).

Comment: @RobW According to the MDN, the attr() function you're referring to is the one from CSS2.1, I'm referring to the CSS3 one.

Comment: W3C (CSS3) spec for those interested: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#attr

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Looking at the grammar that's given in the spec:

```
attr( <attr-name> <type-or-unit>? [ , <fallback> ]? )
```

It looks like the comma between the attribute name and the unit to be used needs to be dropped:

```css
.window > .content .wbutton.tint {
    border: solid thin attr(data-tint color);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px attr(data-tint color);
}
```

However, even if you have the right syntax, it won't work either. It turns out, **there are no known implementations of the level 3 version of `attr()`** as of <del>2012</del>...2020. To make matters worse, [it's still at-risk as of the latest editor's draft of the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#status).

But not all is lost: if you'd like to see this feature implemented in upcoming browsers, there is still time to suggest it in the relevant feedback channels! Here are the proposals that have been put out so far:

- [Microsoft Edge Platform](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csslevel3attrfunction), currently Under Consideration (ht [Lea Verou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90826/lea-verou)!)

For the record, the basic [Level 2.1 version](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#x18) is fully supported across recent versions of all major browsers, including IE8+ and Firefox 2+, and is used with the `content` property for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements for generated content. The MDN browser compatibility table is applicable only to this version, and not the CSS3 version.

Comment: Furthermore, you *cannot* assume that a browser implements a CSS3 feature until the module has been or is being finalized in at least the CR phase. As a draft, anything can come and go. In fact, there's speculation that the `attr()` function may be dropped during the CR phase... but realistically speaking, I wouldn't bet on that happening either. Personally, I would just wait and see.

Comment: I'll wait for full support of CSS3 then. (Damn SO won't let me edit my previous comment)

Comment: Just so you know, CSS3 has reached CR now. `calc()` is now supported in every major browser apart from Opera (on Webkit browsers `-webkit-` prefixed, on the rest not), `attr()` is not yet available AFAIK. :(

Comment: @m_gol: I hope they implement it soon, otherwise it's going to bounce back to LCWD and time will be wasted. That gets annoying.

Comment: @m_gol `attr()` is currently supported, at least partially, in Chrome (haven't checked on other browsers yet). See http://archive.simurai.com/lab/buttons/ for an example of its use.

Comment: @Marnen Laibow-Koser: That's CSS2.1 `attr()`, which like I said is fully supported by all browsers. We're talking about CSS3 `attr()`, which has no support beyond what CSS2.1 allows.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, I see. I didn't know `attr()` even existed in CSS 2.1, but having looked at the spec again, I see that it's only the multiargument form that's new in CSS 3. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Douwe Maan: Oh hey... it's been a while.

Comment: Heh, so it has. Yo @BoltClock :)

Answer (score 10):

As of today, the `attr()` in CSS3 only supports to get values from the HTML5 `data` attribute to set the `content` of an element. There is a nice [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/wp7Wc/4/) whichs shows it.

I have tested it in Google Chrome 35, Mozilla Firefox 30 & Internet Explorer 11.

If you want to use HTML5 data attributes for different things in CSS3, like setting the `width` and the `height` of elements, then you need an additional JavaScript library.

Fabrice Weinberg wrote a [CSS3 attr() Polyfill](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/Dsdkr) which handles `data-width` and `data-height`. You can find Fabrice's GitHub repository here: [cssattr.js](https://github.com/FWeinb/cssattr.js).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One consideration you may want to make in the example JS fiddle is to have a comment saying how you *don't* expect the width style to get updated, as some (like myself) may first expect to see the width take effect until reading your full answer.

Comment: It's not limited to HTML5 data attributes. It can be used with any attribute, whether standard or non-standard. The only limitation is its use with the CSS `content` property.

Comment: Please refrain from using *exact* temporal terms such as "as of today" because such are irrelevant for Stackoverflow questions. Your "today" is already years ago in the past.

Answer (score 4):

I found hack. This is not attribute, but manipulate directly on styles. In Chrome Canary, you can use custom css properties, and JS for manipulate properties.

In CSS:

```
.some { background-position: var(--x) 0; }
```

In JS:

```
element.style.setProperty("--x", "100px", "");
//With same success you can set attribute.
```

Test case: https://jsfiddle.net/y0oer8dk/

Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/0ysxxmj9/2/

Comment: I like this idea as a solution, because it allows for more dynamic options. In my case I needed access the `<ol>` `start` attribute for a custom counter. It's been a long day for something so simple, and this approach seems to be the more elegant in my view. Here is what I wound up doing, which would be easily adapted to any other attribute as needed...

`$( document ).ready(function() { $('[start]').each(function() { this.style.setProperty('--start', this.getAttribute('start')); }) });`

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but not the way you think. It's not a value that's sent via a variable but more as a trigger to then assign a value to. And because of this it's better to make the data attributes something unique but simple.
A small example might help:

```
<div class="data"><span data-width="80" data-tint="lime"></span></div>
```

Then in your css you would put:

```
.data {height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: #eee;}
.data > span {display: block; height: 100%;}
.data > span[data-width="80"] {width: 80%;}
.data > span[data-tint="lime"] {background-color: rgba(118, 255, 3, 0.6);}
```

It's pointless if your doing it on a small scale but on a larger scale and with some help from SCSS some things become easier, like..

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    &[data-width="#{$i}"] {
        .data > span {
            width: calc(#{$i} * 1%);
        }
    }
}
```

That will compile into CSS every percentage possibility allowing you to set your span width with data-width.

[Check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uge44/nadr716q/31/)

Comment: "It's not a value that's sent via a variable" - But that's literally what the W3C spec says it is.

Comment: Can you give us the link to that because I've been going by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes and I can't find anything like that there.

Comment: It's the first link in my question.

Comment: Ok. I haven't read that before and in my experience using the data attribute it that way only works in pseudo elements in content. It specifically says the color has to be either the hex value or an ident css token which I understand as the names of colors that css understands, so rgba wouldn't work and when I tried it out it doesn't work with hex or names either.

Comment: That's the thing: The W3C says it should work like that, but not a single browser does it that way. Even now, over 6 years after I asked this question.

Comment: Haha, It's a crazy world we live in. But all we can do is what we can.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to accomplish can't currently be achieved with data attributes as has been said by several people already. While the answer from @Eugene will work, it will add an incredible amount of bloat to your css file and is therefore unreasonable. @benny-neugebauer was correct in saying that it isn't possible with data attributes but he isn't entirely correct in saying that you need javascript to accomplish it. There is a way to achieve it with html and css only...

We need to start by converting your attribute from a data attribute to a css variable.

```
<a class="wbutton tint" data-tint="rgba(255,0,0,.5)" href="#">This should be red, with an opacity of 0.5</a>
```

becomes

```
<a class="wbutton tint" href="#" style="--data-tint:rgba(255,0,0,.5);">This should be red, with an opacity of .5</a>
```

Next, we need to modify your css slightly. It should also be noted that since you used a comma in your `attr()`, where you have `color` is where you are supposed to, or can, include a fallback in case your variable is invalid. If you wanted to declare that the attribute value should be a color then you would not use the comma.

```
.window > .content .wbutton.tint {
  border: solid thin attr(data-tint, color);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px attr(data-tint, color);
}
```

becomes

```
.window > .content .wbutton.tint {
  border: solid thin var(--data-tint);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px var(--data-tint);
}
```

You can see it in action below.

```css
.window>.content .wbutton.tint {
  border: solid thin var(--data-tint);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px var(--data-tint);
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="wbutton tint" href="#" style="--data-tint:rgba(255,0,0,.5);">This should be red, with an opacity of .5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an [article by Chris Coyier at css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/) that provides more information.