# Why do firefox & chrome fail to accept attr() in CSS with pseudo-elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[This is what I tried in `JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/SwJCm/). It's working fine in JSFiddle.  I am able to access 
`attr()` that is associated with CSS.  But when I try this in Firefox and Chrome the browsers are not ready to accept it.  Firefox immediately discards this property, and Chrome strikes it and adds a warning symbol.  Why are these browsers not accepting this `attr()`?  How does JSFiddle accept it?

```
$('div').hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).attr('data-content',':over');
        alert($(this).attr('number'));
    },
    function()
    {
       $(this).attr('data-content',':out');
       alert($(this).attr('number',200+parseInt($(this).attr('number'))));
    }
);

div::after 
{
    content: attr(data-content);
    top: attr(number px);
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle isn't a browser. It also isn't a compiler, so it doesn't spit errors at you at code that does not appear to work in the browser.

Comment: Where are you putting these functions? They are firing differently depending on browsers if you put it in your `$(document).ready` handler or `window.onload` handler.

Comment: @BoltClock, Fine. Then isn't possible to get/set attr() ?

Comment: These functions are placed under document.ready

Comment: I have seen JSFidle documentation and FAQ. If anything doesn't work in browsers but working in JSFiddle , they are advised us to add all the libraries they added . Is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `attr()` doesn't work with anything but the `content` property at the moment, because that's the only property it was defined for in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content), which is the only version of `attr()` that all browsers support at the moment. The more expansive version of `attr()`, defined in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation), isn't supported by any browsers yet — see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers).

If you really need to set the `top` property or any other property of a pseudo-element according to a data attribute value, you'll have to take the long route: you'll need to alter the document stylesheet using JavaScript, e.g. by using `addRule()`/`insertRule()` with jQuery's `.attr()` method to construct your CSS rules. [You can't directly access pseudo-elements using jQuery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after/5041526#5041526)

Comment: Yeah ! I have seen this answer already that it doesn't work with others except content. But i am little bit confused with the example 20 at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation

Comment: What about it confuses you?

Comment: I want to access top property of a pseudo-element. I have found lots of answers including yours too like 'addRules', 'insertRule' , 'attr()' .. but none of them are working.

Comment: They used attr() with width property. That's the thing confused me

Comment: Yes, those are examples of how the spec works. The problem is that browsers don't support the new spec yet, which is why it doesn't really work.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your comment. So the problem is with browsers!! Is there any way to access top property of a pseudo-element.