# How to set the content property of an `after` pseudo-element to an attribute of a sibling form element

Tags: css, css-content

Is there any way, using CSS, to set the content of an `after` pseudo-element to an attribute of a sibling form element?

For example:

```css
p:after{
  content: +select(attr(title));
}
```

```html
<p>Message: </p>

<select>
  <option title="Hi" value="1">Hi</option>
  <option title="Hello" value="2" selected>Hello</option>
  <option title="Goodbye" value="3">Goodbye</option>
</select>
```

The desired rendered output in this example would be: `Message: Hello`

If this is not currently possible, are there any plans in the CSS4 (or 5?) specification to allow the use of selectors in the `content` property?

I have a jQuery solution, however I am curious if this is something I could do without javascript?

Comment: unfortunately, it is not possible via CSS. this kind of possibilitie would be great in many ways :)

Comment: There is nothing like CSS4 and there will be no CSS5. - And to your question. JavaScript is designed to make pages dynamic. In your case its the way to go.

Comment: Technically it's CSS level 4 (and CSS level 3). No confusion possible as thre's no CSS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attr()` function can only take an attribute from the originating element, both in [CSS level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#x18) and [CSS Values level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation) (the latter of which [hasn't even been implemented yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922)).

Work hasn't started on a level 4 module yet, but given the introduction of a [Non-element Selectors module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-nonelement), which currently features an attribute node selector, it wouldn't be that far-fetched to incorporate such a feature into a level 4 `attr()` function. But considering the lack of interest in implementing the level 3 `attr()`, which has been at-risk for *years* now, I really wouldn't hold my breath. Which is a real shame, because I too see a lot of potential in the CSS `attr()` function for authors.

Answer (score -3):

Hahaha LOL .. just sharing how funny is this ..

```js
$( 'p' ).after('<style></style>');
$( 'select' ).on( 'change', function(){
//$( 'p' ).text('Message: ' +$( 'select option:selected' ).text());
$( 'style' ).html('p:after{content: "'+$( 'select option:selected' ).text()+'" }');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Message: </p>

<select>
  <option title="Hi" value="1">Hi</option>
  <option title="Hello" value="2" selected>Hello</option>
  <option title="Goodbye" value="3">Goodbye</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is pretty much the solution I have at the moment. I'm just interested if there is a CSS only solution.