# How to target flex item by its order number?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, flexbox

I need to rearrange my *flex items* in their container programmatically, but I can't seem to find how to select them by their `order` numbers. The problem is that they are not shown in their DOM order, but using `order` css attribute.

> How do I rearrange them?

my html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div style="order: 17"></div>
    <div style="order: 25"></div>
    <div style="order: 2"></div>
    <div style="order: 3"></div>
    // ...
</div>
```

Basically I need to do this:

```
| A | B | C | D | E |
       +----------->
     <---+---+---+
result:
| A | C | D | E | B |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I got an idea to abuse CSS3 selectors a bit and it seems to be working, though I wonder how *legit* this is.

```
document.querySelector('div[style*="order: 25;"]')
```

Then to swap two items I need to do this:

```
var t = document.querySelector('div[style*="order: 25;"]');
document.querySelector('div[style*="order: 26;"]').style.order = 25;
t.style.order = 26;
```

Comment: This will work perfectly provided every flex item is guaranteed to have the style attribute with its own ordinal number and the style declaration itself is written and/or serialized consistently. Unfortunately, [CSS3 `attr()` isn't implemented anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922), otherwise you would have been able to make this much cleaner by replacing the inline style with a data attribute and using something like `#container > div { order: attr(data-order integer); }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the flex items according to their computed `order`.

Note that, in case two flex items have the same `order`, they should be ordered according to their DOM position. That is, the sort must be stable. Since `[].sort` is not necessarily stable, I will use a custom implementation of [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

```js
var orderedChildren = mergeSort([].map.call(
  document.getElementById('container').children,
  function(child) {
    return [child, +getComputedStyle(child).order];
  }
)).map(function(pair) {
  return pair[0];
});
function mergeSort(arr) {
  var m = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  if(!m) return arr;
  var arr2 = mergeSort(arr.splice(m)),
      arr1 = mergeSort(arr.splice(0));
  while(arr1.length && arr2.length)
    arr.push((arr1[0][1] > arr2[0][1] ? arr2 : arr1).shift());
  return arr.concat(arr1, arr2);
}
```

```js
var orderedChildren = mergeSort([].map.call(
  document.getElementById('container').children,
  function(child) {
    return [child, +getComputedStyle(child).order];
  }
)).map(function(pair) {
  return pair[0];
});
function mergeSort(arr) {
  var m = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  if(!m) return arr;
  var arr2 = mergeSort(arr.splice(m)),
      arr1 = mergeSort(arr.splice(0));
  while(arr1.length && arr2.length)
    arr.push((arr1[0][1] > arr2[0][1] ? arr2 : arr1).shift());
  return arr.concat(arr1, arr2);
}
for(var i=0; i<orderedChildren.length; ++i) {
  orderedChildren[i].textContent = i;
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="order: 17"></div>
  <div style="order: 25"></div>
  <div style="order: 2"></div>
  <div style="order: 3"></div>
  <div style="order: 17"></div>
  <div style=""></div>
  <div style="order: -17"></div>
  <div style="order: 2"></div>
</div>
If the numbers are ordered, it means JS has iterated the flex items according to their <code>order</code> property.
```