# Get attribute value in LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

In `css` we have something similair for `:pseudo` elements. According to **[this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation)**, it will come in the future. At the moment its not supported by any major browser **http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr**

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    color: attr(data-color); /* Doens't work in css */
    width: attr(data-width px);
}

.test:after {
    content: attr(data-name);
}
```

```html
<div class='test' data-name=" - CONTENT" data-color="#f00" data-width="200">test</div>
```

But what i want is, lets say ive the following `div`

```
<div data-color="#f00">...</div>
```

In `LESS` i want to be able to pick that color through the `data` attribute.

```
.example-class { 
    color: attr(data-color); /* Something like this */
}
```

Is this, or something similar, possible using `LESS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that LESS compiles to CSS anyway, and therefore never knows about the HTML, that doesn't seem possible. That is the entire reason why the `attr()` function is in CSS, not LESS.

Comment: Hm, that's too bad. There is really no css alternative is there? My only option will be `js` then?

Comment: @Richard Mauritz: Yeah, pretty much. Believe me, you're not the only one frustrated by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922

Comment: *There is really no css alternative is there?* Unless you need something more complex than just color/width the vanilla 30-years-old-HTML has what you want: `<div style="color: #f00; width: 200px">`.

Comment: The style attribute didn't appear until the late 90s, but yeah pretty much.