# How To Use attribute values in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Look There:

```css
a[target="_blank"]{
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<a target="_blank">Im Red</a>
<br>
<a>Im Normal</a>
```

Its Correct But Can I Have **ATTRIBUTE VALUE**?

Like This:

```css
*[colorAttrib]{
        color:/* value of colorAttrib */;
    }
```

```html
<p colorAttrib="red">I Want To Be Red</p>
<p colorAttrib="blue">I Want To Be Blue</p>
```

That the **FIRST** paragraph is **RED** and the **SECOND** paragraph is **BLUE**.

Comment: You can use [`data-*`](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-why-use-html5-custom-data-attributes/) for that.

Comment: Sure, I say some examples...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using data attributes for this particular task. [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) has an excellent overview of what they are, how they work, and what kind of support they have.

> The `data-*` attribute gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.

```css
*[data-color='red'] { color: red; }
*[data-color='blue'] { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p data-color="red">I am red.</p>
<p data-color="blue">I am blue.</p>
```

With regards to your comment:

> But How About When I Have 1000 Values?!

Your limit is really your imagination here. For example, I'll expand this out:

```css
*[data-color='red'] { color: red; }
*[data-color='blue'] { color: blue; }
*[data-color='green'] { color: green; }
*[data-color='normal'] { color: black; }
*[data-color='gradient'] {
  background: #1CB5E0;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #000046, #1CB5E0);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0000aa, #1CB5E0);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
*[data-color='poly'] { color: #f95; }
*[data-color='asq93'] { color: #a5c; }
```

```html
<p data-color="red">I am red.</p>
<p data-color="blue">I am blue.</p>
<p data-color="green">I am green.</p>
<p data-color="normal">I am normal.</p>
<p data-color="gradient">I am gradient.</p>
<p data-color="poly">I am poly.</p>
<p data-color="asq93">I am asq93.</p>
```

Comment: OK, I Can Do It While I Have Only Blue And Red;

Comment: But How About When I Have 1000 Values?!

Comment: There's really no limit on how many you can do, I'll reflect that in my answer.

Comment: So when I have 1000 different values, if I want to write a single line of code for each of them, the CSS file size will increase a lot!

Comment: @M.HSarmadi that's correct, but a different issue altogether.

Comment: Eventually, you should be able to use the `attr()` function, [but don't hold your breath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769922/215552) as it hasn't gotten anywhere in years.